# Not able to create index on elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I am using elasticsearch with logstash to visualize a data set with kibana.

I created a config file as per the specifications, have my elasticsearch and kibana up and running and then loading the config file. I am getting the below as the message when i am done loading the file. I know the file has not loaded as i would have seen the data sets in the prompt. I also searched for the index in kibana dashboard but it does not show me the index.

Below is the prompt message i get:

```
Thread.exclusive is deprecated, use Thread::Mutex
Sending Logstash logs to D:/AMS/Softwares/logstash-7.4.2/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-11-25T14:05:08,406][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2019-11-25T14:05:08,429][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.4.2"}
[2019-11-25T14:05:10,623][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 42 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 20 keys and 40 values
[2019-11-25T14:05:11,458][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] You are using a deprecated config setting "document_type" set in elasticsearch. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. Document types are being deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.0, and removed entirely in 7.0. You should avoid this feature If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"document_type", :plugin=><LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch index=>"Imports", id=>"7195e24081a8419104011573b541ec87e57c49b74d413cad474911f90ee68a82", hosts=>[//localhost], document_type=>"Imports20162017", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_9e38ae5e-1762-4e76-9a15-bf2e71e368a8", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, workers=>1, manage_template=>true, template_name=>"logstash", template_overwrite=>false, doc_as_upsert=>false, script_type=>"inline", script_lang=>"painless", script_var_name=>"event", scripted_upsert=>false, retry_initial_interval=>2, retry_max_interval=>64, retry_on_conflict=>1, ilm_enabled=>"auto", ilm_rollover_alias=>"logstash", ilm_pattern=>"{now/d}-000001", ilm_policy=>"logstash-policy", action=>"index", ssl_certificate_verification=>true, sniffing=>false, sniffing_delay=>5, timeout=>60, pool_max=>1000, pool_max_per_route=>100, resurrect_delay=>5, validate_after_inactivity=>10000, http_compression=>false>}
[2019-11-25T14:05:12,021][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://localhost:9200/]}}
[2019-11-25T14:05:12,260][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"http://localhost:9200/"}
[2019-11-25T14:05:12,322][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] ES Output version determined {:es_version=>7}
[2019-11-25T14:05:12,327][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2019-11-25T14:05:12,375][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["//localhost"]}
[2019-11-25T14:05:12,450][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using default mapping template
[2019-11-25T14:05:12,549][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"index_patterns"=>"logstash-*", "version"=>60001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s", "number_of_shards"=>1}, "mappings"=>{"dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "ignore_above"=>256}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date"}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}
[2019-11-25T14:05:12,565][WARN ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge][main] A gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.specialized.RubyArrayOneObject) has been create for key: cluster_uuids. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development team.
[2019-11-25T14:05:12,572][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500, :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3f750db6 run>"}
[2019-11-25T14:05:15,423][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<ArgumentError: File paths must be absolute, relative path specified: D:\\AMS\\Docs\\ELK Related\\Data Set\\import-and-export-by-india\\PC_Import_2016_2017.csv>, :backtrace=>["D:/AMS/Softwares/logstash-7.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.1.11/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:269:in `block in register'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1800:in `each'", "D:/AMS/Softwares/logstash-7.4.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.1.11/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:267:in `register'", "D:/AMS/Softwares/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:195:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1800:in `each'", "D:/AMS/Softwares/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:194:in `register_plugins'", "D:/AMS/Softwares/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:296:in `start_inputs'", "D:/AMS/Softwares/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:252:in `start_workers'", "D:/AMS/Softwares/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:149:in `run'", "D:/AMS/Softwares/logstash-7.4.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:108:in `block in start'"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3f750db6 run>"}
[2019-11-25T14:05:15,452][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
[2019-11-25T14:05:15,848][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2019-11-25T14:05:20,768][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
```

Below is the logstash file i am using:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "D:\\AMS\\Docs\\ELK Related\\Data Set\\import-and-export-by-india\\PC_Import_2016_2017.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "nul"
  }
}

filter {
  csv {
    separator => ","
    columns => [ "pc_code", "pc_description", "unit", "country_code", "country_name", "quantity", "value" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost"
    index => "Imports"
    document_type => "Imports20162017"
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong that i am doing?

*Solved*

The issue was the backslashes used in file path. I used forward slashes instead and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this error:

> File paths must be absolute, relative path specified

You need to get rid of the backslashes in your path and use forward slashes instead, like this:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "D:/AMS/Docs/ELK Related/Data Set/import-and-export-by-india/PC_Import_2016_2017.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "nul"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..i got this resolved..it, actually, was because of the backslashes. Instead I used forwards slashes and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To visualize and explore data in Kibana, you must create an index pattern. An index pattern tells Kibana which Elasticsearch indices contain the data that you want to work with. An index pattern can match a single index, multiple indices, and a rollup index.

Goto Management>>Index Patterns>>+Create Index Patterns

[image].

You should be able to visualize your doc input once you are done with this.

Get more details here [Index patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html)