# is there any easy way to push the data to elasticsearch via logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, elasticsearch-5

This is my logstash code

```
input {
    file {
       path => "C:/Users/Rajaraman/Documents/logstashfiles/demo.txt"
       start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
filter {}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    }
}
```

Logstash is running fine but index not created in elastic search

Comment: This thread should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59032554/4604579

Comment: I cannot see the data flow on elastic search. but logstatsh is running fine[2020-03-25T12:26:43,805][INFO ][logstash.inputs.file     ][main] No sincedb_path set, }
[2020-03-25T12:26:44,572][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}

Comment: I see `No sincedb_path set` in the log your provide. Did you add the `sincedb_path` setting to your `file` input as shown in the linked thread?

Comment: It worked fine as of now .. Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if your logstash is doing anything do:

```
$ curl -XGET 'localhost:9600/_node/stats/events?pretty'
{
  "events" : {
    "in" : 293658,
    "filtered" : 293658,
    "out" : 293658,
    "duration_in_millis" : 2324391,
    "queue_push_duration_in_millis" : 343816
  }
```